# Spring data JPA Hibernate session memory leakage

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

we have spring boot application which uses JPA+hibernate for database access. We observed that the JVM heap size is going up to 600 MB and the heap dump shows its the hibernate session factory using all the heap space.

Please advice what to be done in the JPA repository access. Most of the entity operation's are read-only and we have made the Transaction(readOnly=true), to prevent the hibernate dirty checking.

To load the 30 to 40 entities we have i think 600 MB is too much of heap space and we want to reduce this to less than 200 MB.

Appreciate your inputs

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a profiler to see exactly what is taking space and how much.

Do you know [visual vm](https://visualvm.java.net/)?

Comment: yes. with visualvm its showing lots of hibernate session factory instances.